# Uncaught ReferenceError: new_balance is not defined

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add two integers from inputs and display it in the other one, but I'm having undefined variable error,

```
var txn_type = $("#txn_type").val();
var amount = $("#Amount").val();
var current_balance = $("#current_balance").val();

if (txn_type == 'Credit') {
  var new_balance = parseFloat(current_balance) + parseFloat(amount);
} else {
  var new_balance = parseFloat(current_balance) - parseFloat(amount);
}
console.log(new_balance);
$("#new_balance").val(new_balance);
```

Comment: Can you paste your html code as well?

Comment: Please add your HTML OR complete code so someone can address this issue properly for you. Thanks